# Change value inside of table by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a table value that changes by id application with jquery and i don't know about jquery that much how can i change table row by id from input with jquery

note:i tested following code from another page but the code is like this

```
 `<script>
     $('#dicerik').html(icerik).find("#tablo2"); 
 </script>`
```

i have tried something like this but i cant scope the real way this changes some other row

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>İçerik</th>
    <th>Tür</th>
    <th>Dil</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>DENEXAMPLE</td>
    <td>YineEXAMPLE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>DENEXAMPLE2</td>
    <td>YineEXAMPLE2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>DENEXAMPLE3</td>
    <td>YineEXAMPLE3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>DENEXAMPLE4</td>
    <td>YineEXAMPLE4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" placeholder="id">
<input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" placeholder="text">
<button type="button" name="butonbu">Change it</button>
```

first input id of a row example 1 and its second text YineEXAMPLE

expected result is id 1 row and second text should be "dene"

Comment: which value you want to change

Comment: Show us some expected output

Comment: it doesnt matter an example changing id 1 table row and DENEXAMPLE3 can be Replaced with DENEME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you want to find a row in table by particular id and change 2nd or 3rd column, isn't it?

You need go through each row, get text from the first cell, if this text is equal to required value, you have to change the value in other cell.

You can do it with using this code:

```
$('button[name=butonbu]').click(function () {
    var id = $('#text1').val();
    var newText = $('#text2').val();
    $('table tr').each(function (index, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        if ($el.find('td:first').text() === id) {        
            $el.find('td:nth-child(2)').text(newText);
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/js7yg631/7/

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>İçerik</th>
    <th>Tür</th>
    <th>Dil</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>DENEXAMPLE</td>
    <td>YineEXAMPLE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>DENEXAMPLE2</td>
    <td>YineEXAMPLE2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>DENEXAMPLE3</td>
    <td>YineEXAMPLE3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>DENEXAMPLE4</td>
    <td>YineEXAMPLE4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" placeholder="id">
<input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" placeholder="text">
<button type="button" name="butonbu" onClick="changeIt()">Change it</button>

<script>
function changeIt()
{
  $("table tr").each(function(index)
  {
     if (index != 0) {
     $row = $(this);

     var id = $row.find("td:first").text();
     var searchID=$("#text1").val();
     
     if(id==searchID)
     {
         $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").html($("#text2").val())
     }
  }

})
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i do it with plain javascript 
try this

```
    <table>
    <tr id="tr-0">
        <th>İçerik</th>
        <th>Tür</th>
        <th>Dil</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>DENEXAMPLE</td>
        <td>YineEXAMPLE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-2">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>DENEXAMPLE2</td>
        <td>YineEXAMPLE2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-3">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>DENEXAMPLE3</td>
        <td>YineEXAMPLE3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-4">
        <td>4</td>
        <td>DENEXAMPLE4</td>
        <td>YineEXAMPLE4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" placeholder="id">
<input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" placeholder="text">
<input type="text" id="text3" name="text2" placeholder="text">
<button type="button" id="submit" name="butonbu">Change it</button>
<script>
    const input1 = document.getElementById('text1')
    const input2 = document.getElementById('text2')
    const input3 = document.getElementById('text3')
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', changetarget)

    function changetarget() {
        if (input1.value != '' || input2.value != '' || input3.value != '') {
            let parentTr = document.getElementById('tr-' + input1.value);
            parentTr.children[1].innerHTML = input2.value;
            parentTr.children[2].innerHTML = input3.value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('button[name=butonbu]').on("click", function(){
        var id = $("#text1").val();
        var replace_with = $("#text2").val();

        $( "tr" ).each( function( index ) {
            if(index !== 0){
                var col_val = $(this).children("td").html();
                if( col_val == id ){
                    $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)").html(replace_with);
                }
            }                       
        });
    });
});
```